# Are there official stats for Elminster, Laeral Silverhand, and Khelben Arunsun?

Tags: dnd-5e, npc

Is there any books that include stats for Elminster, Laeral Silverhand, and Khelben Arunsun? I would prefer 5e, but if WotC hasn't done that yet, any of the earlier editions would work.

Comment: Is there a reason you are looking for those stat blocks? What have you done yourself to try to find them (ie. show your research)?

Answer (score 12):

## Only for Silverhand

I can't speak for previous editions, but do note that stat blocks are not compatible between editions as the rules surrounding them are quite different.

To find a official version of a given monster, you can use the [monster search function](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters) on D&D Beyond. Doing so for the three names you've listed only gives a result for [Laeral Silverhand](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/laeral-silverhand), who was included in *Waterdeep: Dragon Heist*.

Comment: To be perfectly honest I never understood why we would need them. These personalities really shouldn't be encountered in any adversarial capacity and even if they did it is unlikely given all their assets and connections PCs would have any real chance of besting them. But maybe I just don't get it... seems much like the Deities and Demigods books way back when everyone basically said "if it has stats we can kill it" and everyone hunted the gods down. Dark days of D&D past.

Comment: @Slagmoth from a Dragon Heist perspective, there is some chance Laeral might help the adventurers. Also if you continue the campaign on after the resolution of the published book, there is specific actions the PCs might take (in the campaign) that put them at odds with Laeral longer term. This is particularly true if they continue into Undermountain and actually reach level 20.

Comment: You might add that _Waterdeep: Dragon Heist_, in addition to containing stats for Laeral, confirms Elminster to be alive and Khelben to be dead at the time of the adventure.

Answer (score 2):

Of the three, an official statblock has been given only for Laeral Silverhand so far. It appears in the *Waterdeep: Dragon Heist* adventure. She is weaker than in past editions thanks to Mystra’s death and rebirth.

Khelben Arunsun is dead, and his soul is in the new Blackstaff wielded by Vajra Safahr (18th-level wizard). Elminster still hasn’t got stats, but I would consider Acererak and Vlaakith as good guidelines.

Comment: Elminster is closer to Laeral than to either of the liches you mention, given that he is a Chosen of Mystra.

Comment: In position: Yes. In Power: he is closer to Acererak (since Laeral now is “only” a 19th level wizard that can cast all 2th and 1th level spells at will).